# ExtractData from GET Paramter and load content from .json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, query-string

I have a html page (product page) which now I have to fill with content from a .json file (array with different products, accessible via id). In the url you should be able to set a GET parameter like this:

```
/product?product_id=14
```

I know that no more information will be passed in the url, so I don't need to use any regex.

Now I simply have no idea to get the content into my html file, all I know so far is (js file):

```
let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
if (h1) {
  h1.textContent = '#1';
} else {
  console.log('#1: No content found!');
}
```

So now I need to know which id was passed via GET parameter and how to load the content from the .json database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to get the parameter from the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20336097/7303349

And then getting the json database sounds like an entirely different step. Try to do less things at a time. Also, where does the .json database come from?

Comment: the only reason for the .json file is to store all products in an array, this file is given to build my html page on